# discord dispatcher property is not founded

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm making discord music bot using discord.js
I found out I have to use the `serverQueue.connection.dispatcher` property in the example code I saw

but there is not dispatcher property
So what should I do?

```
switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
    case '⏸️':
        if (!serverQueue.playing) return;
        serverQueue.playing = false;
        return serverQueue
    case '▶️':
        if (serverQueue.playing) return;
        serverQueue.playing = true;
        return serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.resume();
    case '⏹️':
        this.client.queue.delete(guild.id);
        return voice.channel.leave();
    case '⏩':
        return serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
    case '':
        return serverQueue.loop = !serverQueue.loop;
        default:
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js no longer comes with voice support since the release of v13. You need to use **[@discordjs/voice](https://npmjs.com/package/@discordjs/voice)** in order to get things done.

This new voice library removed the concept of `dispatcher`. You can find some examples written by discord.js developers **[here](https://github.com/discordjs/voice/tree/main/examples)**.